# Image/shape appears incorrectly VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, image, position, shapes

I have a very simple code to put the image to align with cell M2.

```
Dim picNameDefault as String
picNameDefault = "ProcessingDocument"
Dim img As Shape
Set img = ActiveSheet.Shapes(picNameDefault)
img.Top = Range("M2").Top
img.Left = Range("M2").Left
Debug.Print img.Top
Debug.Print img.Left
Debug.Print Range("M2").Top
Debug.Print Range("M2").Left
```

All locations (the last `Debug.Print` 4 lines) appears to be correct (top = top, left=left). However in the sheet, the picture move as in picture attached (first is before, second is after running code). This is a document entry UI, the picture to be moved is the document to be keyed. I have no idea what happened as other times, it works correctly.
[image: Before running code]
[image: After running code]

Comment: Can this is caused by original picture's (in hard drive) orientation? Just a hunch, I have no idea how to get information of that using VBA.

Comment: And what the `Debug.Print` part returns about the `Left` - `Top` values for both cases? Are they the same?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, they are.

Comment: Please, try `Debug.Print img.Rotation`. What does it return in Imediate Window?

Comment: It's 90. The rotation of the image in the hard drive is incorrect so I rotated upright.

Comment: The reason is not important. VBA arranges it according to its unrotated properties. You should use something like, in fact I will post an answer adapting your code...

Answer (score 1):

Please try the next way. It is designed for clasic rotation, as you said (rotation angles: 0, 90, 270, 180):

```
Sub positionRotatedPict()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, img As Shape, rng As Range
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set img = sh.Shapes("ProcessingDocument")
   Set rng = sh.Range("M4") 'According to the difference between the shape Height/Width, the cell row may be lower.
    img.top = rng.top
    img.left = rng.left
    If img.Rotation = 90 Or img.Rotation = 270 Then
       'Positions are calculated/adapted against half of the difference between the shape height and its width.
       img.top = rng.top - (img.height - img.width) / 2 
        img.left = rng.left + (img.height - img.width) / 2
    End If
End Sub
```

In case of (portret) images with big differences between their height and width, the positioning on top will be wrong for rows near the sheet Top.

Comment: I still haven't get a hold of this. Can you make the code to deal with all 4 main rotation? The documents could get incorrect orientation in more than 1 way.

Comment: @Tam Le  I only tried showing where is the problem and how it can be handled... It is a matter of aritmetic. The shape extremities must be calculated according to the shape rotation. Would you have cases of strange rotation angles, like 156? Or only angles of 90, 270 and 180?

Comment: It's only 0, 90, 180 ,270. If it takes too much of your time, I will refine the code. I have to do it anyway, it will just take me awhile to be familiar with the arithmetic of it.

Comment: @Tam Le OK, it should not be very complicated for these three cases. In principle, 180 should not need anything and 90 should respect the same conditions as 270. But you must understand that **working near the sheet `Top` or `Left` side may create problems**. I mean, if the differences between the shape/image height/width are big, when the shape is firstly positioned, **its Top property may not be the correct one**. I mean, Excel positions it on top of the sheet. Then trying to make calculations against the theoretical `Top` (or `Left`) may not be very accurate. My code will work on "M4" cell.

Comment: @Tam Le OK Even, the theoretical Top position can be calculated, but the code will become  more complicated...

Comment: can you add the part about `Top` property being different than actual location because of rotation to the answer. This answer provide the code to move but not enough explanation of the problem (like the comment) in here.

Comment: @Tam Le Yes, I can, but this is not solving the problem. I must confess that my answer tried to answer your question in terms of explaining why  "images appears incorrectly"... The code I firstly posted was meant to prove that what I am saying is correct. I used some simple arithmetic, in order to solve the positioning problems, but for rows not near the sheet `Top`, which influence the calculations as I tried explaining above. I do  not have time right now, but the solution should be trigonometrically calculated. I mean, the shape must be positioned according to its **rotation center**.

Comment: @Tam Le Yes I will be busy all the day and I do not think I will have time to be involved in such a problem, which I do not need, but I would take it like challenge if some availability appears. If not, I will only try better explaining which are the limitations of the above solution, and why they appear... Being able to calculate the real top **according to its position after rotation**, such a function can position a shape rotated at really any angle. I mean, theoretically. And transforming the theory in something workable takes some time, which I do not have it...